# Excel 2010: count if using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've a table with

- actual stock in column `C`
- goods in arrival in column `D`
- auto-reorder in column `F`

I need to count the number of rows when `(C+D+F) > 0`.
Every row must be counted only one time and only `if (C=0 or D=0 or F=0)`

Is there a way?

I've looked at the most detailed tutorial about countifs on the web from ablebits, but I've not been able to adapt it to fit my needs.

Comment: Yep, look into sumproduct

Comment: @Raystafarian, please provide an example on how I can solve my problem with this function. Anyway, it's interesting a lot !

Comment: You can easily do it with a helper column, I don't know other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a new column to do the calculation first with cells containing the following formula:

```
=AND( ((A2+B2+C2)>0), OR( A2=0, B2=0, C2=0) )
```

NB: I've only used columns A, B & C here for simplicity.

The new column will show true or false.

For your count, you need the formula:

```
=COUNTIF([test],TRUE)
```

NB: I turned the data table into an Excel table which is always best practice. It turned on the Total Row for the table and changed the default formula to the one above. The column that I added for the previous formula, I gave a heading of "test" to. Doing things this way makes sure you always include the whole table for the calculation as Excel handles the dynamic updating of the rows/columns/cells. You can also put the totals in a row above the data table which is great for large tables.

UPDATE:

If you make the data table an Excel table as I suggest, you can also change you first column formula to:

```
=AND( (([@stock]+[@in]+[@reorder])>0), OR( [@stock]=0, [@in]=0, [@reorder]=0) )
```

Assuming you have headed the columns "stock", "in" and "reorder" respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a single-formula solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((C=0)+(D=0)+(F=0))>0)*(C+D+F>0))
```

Note that I've used just the column letter to refer to your entire data range. It'll actually be something like `$C$2:$C$500` or `Table1[Actual Stock]` or whatever your actually data setup requires.

Answer (score 2):

For your condition C=0 or D=0 or E=0, I assume the requirement is that **at least** one item equal zero, not that **exactly** one item must equal zero; so for example, C=0 and D=0 would meet the requirement.  If that's the case, there is a simple solution, somewhat similar in approach to Julian Knight's.  I would also use a helper column.  For row 1, it would contain:

```
=(C1+D1+F1>0)*(C1*D1*F1=0)
```

This will return `1` if both conditions are met, zero otherwise.  Copy that down the column for all rows.  Sum that column for the count.